# Building different projects using same build controller

Tags: tfs

I have two project collections on same TFS, i have to assign build controller to each project collection. I see only one build controller in TFS Admin Console. How can i assign build controller to different project collections on same TFS?

Additionally, How can i build projects in different project collections on same TFS, simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Build controller can be tied to only one project collection so you need 2 build controllers. Build service host (windows service on the box) supports only 1 build controller so you will have to install another instance of build service host using the hack in the article below.

As the article suggests: **this is not a supported configuration of the TFS Build Service – use it at your own risk.**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/04/13/configuring-multiple-tfs-build-services-on-one-machine.aspx

Alternately, you can have another box for your 2nd build controller (by installing build service host) and then tie that to your 2nd collection.